# Extract keywords PDFs and export it to a excel file using python?

Tags: python, pdfminer

How can I extract keywords from a set of PDF files, and then export the result to EXCEL File?

I used from subprocess import PIPE, Popen and tried using PDFminer but in vain.

Comment: Your subject says Excel and your question a PDF, what format do you actually want to extract the results?

Comment: I want to extract search keywords from the pdf and export it to EXCEL.